# Praat Pitch Parameters: pitch floor and minimum

Tags: praat

Praat users: I am using a 2-pass method to determine my pitch floor and ceiling. I am first gathering the necessary values using the 'To Pitch...' command. I am then using my calculated floor/ceiling values in the 'To Pitch (cc)...' command, where I am extracting the pitch minimum. Why/how is it that the pitch minimum is lower than my pitch floor?

Example:

Computed pitch floor = 51.2 Computed pitch ceiling = 630.4

Using these values in 'To Pitch (cc)', along with all other parameters set to standard, the pitch minimunm output = 46.0.

How/why is this possible?

Comment: Why are you running `To Pitch (cc)...`? You should be able to get the pitch minimum from `To Pitch...` without needing to run a cross-correlation analysis. Also, are you running `To Pitch (cc)` on the output of `To Pitch` or on the original sound file?

Comment: I originally ran it as such and realized the mistake. I then tried running both with 'To Pitch...' but still have the same result with a minimum below the threshold. I ran everything on the original sound file.